# SQL Server : update table with join condition using JSON input

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-json

I have a table with columns `position_id` and `column_id`. I am getting a JSON response from an API call, and I want to update my table using the value from the JSON response using the `position_id`.

Here is an example

**JSON Table:**

[image]

Table in database(I am calling it `#updateTable`):

[image]

I want to update my `#updateTable` using the JSON input as below:

[image]

How can I achieve that? Is it possible without looping through table. Set based operation would be better I think.

(There are equal number of rows in JSON table and `#updateTable` for a `position_id`).

Here is the code for table creation that I have used in my example.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #inputJSONTable
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #updateTable

DECLARE @inputJSON  nvarchar(max) =
    '[  
       {  
          "column_id":"7",
          "position_id":"787",
          "column1":"GoodValue",
          "column2":"ReplacedValue"
       },
       {  
          "column_id":"8",
          "position_id":"787",
          "column1":"ReplacedValue",
          "column2":"GoodValue"
       }
    ]'

DECLARE @inJSON NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @inJSON = RTRIM(LTRIM(@inputJSON));

SELECT
    *
INTO 
    #inputJSONTable
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@inJSON)
    WITH (
             [column_id] VARCHAR(50) '$.column_id',
             [position_id] VARCHAR(50) '$.position_id',
             [column1] VARCHAR(50) '$.column1',
             [column2] VARCHAR(50) '$.column2'
         );

-- SELECT * FROM #inputJSONTable

CREATE TABLE #updateTable
(
      Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
      column_id INT, 
      position_id INT, 
      column1 VARCHAR(50), 
      column2 VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #updateTable
VALUES (7, 787, 'GoodValue', 'ReplaceME'),
       (8 , 787,  'ReplaceME', 'GoodValue')

SELECT * FROM #inputJSONTable
SELECT * FROM #updateTable
```

Thanks for helping out.

**UPDATE:**

I used this join to update the table :

```
UPDATE up
SET up.column1 = ip.column1,
    up.column2 = ip.column2
FROM #updateTable up 
INNER JOIN #inputJSONTable ip ON up.column_id = ip.column_id
```

Comment: Your JSON doesn't appear to be passing an ID; how do you know what row(s) each entry relates to? Luck that the order the JSON is the same as that in the table? That could likely (will) not be true one day.

Comment: Since both rows have the same `position_id` what column can you use to link the first row of the JSON table with `id` 1 in the update table?

Comment: @Larnu and Tab Allerman ,I see your point. position_id is not enough for this. I will have to alter JSON response or table structure.

Comment: @ProgSky, do you have only 2 value columns, could you try using position_id and column1/column2 to find rows to update?

Comment: @rs. actually its simpler than that, my input has a column_id column that can be used to differentiate which row to update. I have update the question.

Comment: @ProgSky, how do you decide which value needs to be replaced? I know your example says ReplaceMe but it is not clear when to update that, if they are different?

Comment: Yes replace if they are different. I have posted my update with join, does it look good ?

Comment: @ProgSky, that will work ok if you want your table to match json input.

Comment: @rs. yes. payload must match the table columns. I am enforcing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query worked.

```
UPDATE up
SET up.column1 = ip.column1,
    up.column2 = ip.column2
FROM #updateTable up 
INNER JOIN #inputJSONTable ip ON up.column_id = ip.column_id
```